# Regular maps on hyperbolic plane for large number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, conformal-maps

I want to generate large regular maps of a tiling on hyperbolic space. How I can start doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Read [Indra’s Pearls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_Pearls_(book)) by Mumford, Series, and Wright.

Related programs include the following:

- [KBMAG](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/kbmag.html) by Derek Holt
- [MAF](https://maffsa.sourceforge.net/manpages/MAF.html) by Alun Williams
- [Kleinian](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417130946/http://klein.math.okstate.edu/kleinian/src/) by David Wright
- [Honeycombs](http://hyperbolichoneycombs.org/) by Roice Nelson

You may also be interested in some of the on0line communities that discuss fractals.  Here is one of the older ones:

- [Fractal Forum](https://fractalforums.org/)

Comment: How to get the adjacency list of large regular tiling of some graph? (By large means large number of vertices)

Comment: There is no one-line answer to this question.  Please see the book I referred to above.  Once you understand the task, you can use some of the programs listed to produce patches of your tilings.