# Finding automorphism groups of regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, automorphism-groups

Can some body help me with some source code for finding automorphism groups of regular maps?. For example: the type of graph is denoted as $\{p, q\}$, which means that they are tessellations of the plane by regular $p$–gons such that each vertex has coordination number
$q$.
Essentially I want to find automorphism group of $p=8$ and $q=3 (\{8,3\})$ for large number of vertices, say $n=100000$.

Comment: What language are you planning to use, for starters...?

Comment: Sorry I could not get you, you mean which programming language? If so then Mathematica, matlab or python. any one.

Comment: Or GAP, or MAGMA, or and number of other things, and it wasn't clear that you don't really care about the language. MathOverflow is not a programming service to write the code that you want. Imagine you went to Stack Overflow and just asked people to write your code for you—what would happen, do you think?

Comment: Maybe better to ask if there are packages to help with this, in a language of your choice, or resources so you can roll your own in a language that is particularly suited to this type of calculation and so on.

Comment: Sorry if you got it in some other way. In my posted question, I have mentioned 'source code' that means I was expecting a starting point to solve my problem. Ofcourse it is not possible to provide an exact code for some problem.

Comment: Since I am new to stackexchange, so please don't mind. Anyway may i know are there any packages wich can help me with my problem?

Comment: OK, fair enough. I misunderstood what you asked for, and it seemed like you were asking a lot! Apologies for my shortness.

Comment: The graphs you ask about are infinite, but you appear to want to restrict attention to a large finite subgraph. Can you clarify? This will make a huge difference to the automorphism group. (For instance, it will typically cut it down from an infinite group to a small finite group.)

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to calculate the action of the automorphism group on a large subgraph?

Comment: Actully i am working on hyperbolic lattices and i want to generate large regular maps of {8,3} tiling. By large i mean with large number of vertices say n=100000, with their adjacency lists. may i know how i can do that. I am not from math background so I do not have much knowledge on group theory.

Comment: Please give an idea how to generate such large maps with their adjacency matrices?

Comment: Your question in the comments (just above) is the same as your question in the comments elsewhere (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464742/regular-maps-on-hyperbolic-plane-for-large-number-of-vertices).  Like I said before - the answer to your question is "you need to learn a bit of math". I gave several resources as an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 2):

The "full" automorphism group (that is, the automorphisms of the infinite tiling) will be generated by an elliptic element of order $p$ (rotation about a face centre), an elliptic element of order $q$ (rotation about a vertex), and an elliptic element of order two (rotation about an edge centre).  And a reflection, if you allow orientation reversing elements.  These are sometimes called [triangle groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group).

In the euclidean or hyperbolic case, the automorphism group of a patch of the tiling will be finite (at most dihedral, but usually trivial).